# No mouse events on element's backface

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm writing a web app that includes a "card flip" animation similar to the first example on  [this](http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php) page (although I trigger the animation with a click, rather than a hover).  The flip is working, but when the animation is complete and the `backface` is visible, no mouse events register on the element - click, hover, or even text select.  Any ideas why mouse events are not registering?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/3gUPA/

I'm using Chrome 29.  My app only has to work in this browser.

Comment: It sounds like you need to delegate with the `.on()` method since that is the first appearance of the `backface` in the DOM. It would be easier if you'd create a jsFiddle.

Comment: @DevlshOne Check out the fiddle I added in my edit.

Comment: You don't have any mouse events to register once the card is flipped, do you? Not in this fiddle, anyway.

Comment: @DevIshOne Thanks for taking a look.  The `flip-trigger` element should still toggle the `flipped` class, even after the element has been transformed.  Also note that the text on the back face can't be selected, and that the `back-container`'s `cursor: pointer` CSS property is seemingly being ignored.

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/3gUPA/2/)

All you have to do to fix the problems in your comment is change this CSS:

```
.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

Here's what I mean by event delegation...

```
$(".flip-container").on('click','.flip-trigger',function () {
    $(".flip-card").toggleClass("flipped");
});
```

[jQuery .on() event delegation documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Because I've told the `.on()` event to be bound to elements with the `.flip-container` class, it can now be active for any elements presently (or in the future) that are an entity of the NodeList! For instance, `.flip-trigger`, which is tied to the card before it's *flipped*. Now, to get it to flip back over (or whatever else), you can do something like this:

```
$(".flip-container").on('hover','.flipped',function () {
    alert('This is a flipped over card!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm surprised that the .on() method is necessary - isn't the backface already present in the NodeList on page load, just not visilble? Also, why in this example: jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/rDJBp does the .flipped class not need the backface-visiblity property?